# iOS webview app location alerts

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have an HTML map application. Every time I open the application, this pops up:

> [url-to-apps-folder]/[app-name].app/index.html Would like to use your
>   location.

How can I get rid of it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension:"html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is not an iOS issue. Check your HTML file. It is the one that requests the user's permission.

Comment: I added my HTML to main post. I think it's iOS issue because it shows up every time I open the app...

Comment: I don't think you can escape from this. The page is the one that requests for permission and not the app itself. A page will request a permission per session (meaning every time it is loaded in the web view) and a native implementation will request only once. So consider using MKMapView: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/